# Как распределить корабли по карте в "Морском бое"?

Tags: c, алгоритм

```
#define GRID_SIZE 10

int deployment_grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] = {
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},};
```

Надо генерировать корабли в случайных местах, чтобы 
случайно помещенные корабли не касались сторон или углов друг друга и это поместить в поле `deployment_grid`. Как в морском бое.

Список кораблей (# -числа, которые записываются в поле):

```
+--------+------------------+
| #Число | Длина этих чисел |
+--------+------------------+
|      1 |                5 |
|      2 |                4 |
|      3 |                3 |
|      2 |                2 |
|      1 |                1 |
+--------+------------------+
```

Все это записать в функцию `void randomShips()`.

Вот например, на трех картинках случайно генерировались корабли.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем вы видите тут проблему?

Comment: я не вижу проблему,  я не знаю как правильно сделать это

Comment: разве что, вижу проблему в том, что я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Я почему-то подумал, что это ваш код делает приведенные картинки. Вот и решил уточнить, поскольку самого кода в вопросе нет

Comment: В классическом [морском бое](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9_(%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0)) нет пятипалубных кораблей

Comment: В цикле пробуете разместить корабли, если корабль пересекается с другими, перегенерируете координаты, пока корабль не перестанет ни с кем пересекаться.

Comment: очень важная новость  о том, что нет пяти-палубных кораблей.

Comment: да, вот так вот

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define GRID_SIZE 10

int deployment_grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] = {
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},};


typedef enum{
    Left = 0,
    Right = 1,
    Up = 2,
    Down = 3
}Direction;


typedef struct{
    int fill;
    int length;
    Direction dir;
    int row;
    int col;
}Ship;

void createShip(Ship* s, int index, int length, Direction dir, int row, int col){
    s->fill = index;
    s->length = length;
    s->dir = dir;
    s->row = row;
    s->col = col;
}

int positionInGrid(int row, int col){
    if (row < 0 || row >= GRID_SIZE){
        return 0;
    }
    if (col < 0 || col >= GRID_SIZE){
        return 0;
    };
    return 1;
}

int positionIsValid(int row, int col){
    if (!positionInGrid(row, col)){
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = row - 1; i <= row+1; i++){
        for (int j = col -1; j <= col+1; j++){
            if (positionInGrid(i, j)){
                if (deployment_grid[i][j] != 0){
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int shipIsValid(Ship* ship){
    int rowStart = ship->row;
    int colStart = ship->col;
    int rowEnd = rowStart;
    int colEnd = colStart;
    switch (ship->dir) {
    case Left:
        colStart = colEnd - ship->length + 1;
        break;
    case Right:
        colEnd = colStart + ship->length - 1;
        break;
    case Down:
        rowEnd = rowStart + ship->length - 1;
        break;
    case Up:
        rowStart = rowEnd - ship->length + 1;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    for (int row = rowStart; row <= rowEnd; row++){
        for (int col = colStart; col <= colEnd; col++){
            if (!positionIsValid(row, col)){

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void fillShipInGrid(Ship* ship){
    int rowStart = ship->row;
    int colStart = ship->col;
    int rowEnd = rowStart;
    int colEnd = colStart;
    switch (ship->dir) {
    case Left:
        colStart = colEnd - ship->length + 1;
        break;
    case Right:
        colEnd = colStart + ship->length - 1;
        break;
    case Down:
        rowEnd = rowStart + ship->length - 1;
        break;
    case Up:
        rowStart = rowEnd - ship->length + 1;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    for (int row = rowStart; row <= rowEnd; row++){
        for (int col = colStart; col <= colEnd; col++){
            deployment_grid[row][col] = ship->fill;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int shipCount[6] = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1};
    int shipSize[6] = {5,4,3,2,1};
    int fill = 1;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < shipCount[i]; j++){
            int shipCreated = 0;
            while (!shipCreated){
                Direction dir = rand() % 4;
                int row = rand()%10;
                int col = rand()%10;
                int length = shipSize[i];
                Ship s;
                createShip(&s, fill, length, dir, row, col);
                if (shipIsValid(&s)){
                    fill++;
                    shipCreated = 1;
                    fillShipInGrid(&s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++){
            printf("%d ", deployment_grid[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
9 0 0 7 7 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 
0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 
0 0 4 4 4 0 0 8 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
5 0 0 0 0 6 6 6 0 1 
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Спасибо)), я правда уже сам сделал, но хотя бы посмотрю на правильный код ))

Comment: А он не то чтобы правильный. Один из вариантов. @Vladko