# Не понятна причина неправильной работы игры "Морской Бой" (C++)

Tags: c++, циклы

Всё началось с того, что я написал условие несоприкосновения кораблей по диагоналям/вертикалям/горизонталям (частично, всё ещё делаю, но проблема в другом).

Именно в части, где происходит расстановка торпедных катеров (одноклеточных корабликов) происходит зацикливание и ставится один и тот же торпедный катер несмотря на то, что счётчик (на котором, собственно и работает этот цикл, он же `amount_of_checked_cells`) считает кол-во клеток кораблей и по условию при помещении четырёх одноклеточных корабликов должен помещаться двухклеточный кораблик, далее, при установке шести таких клеток - трёхклеточный и так далее... Сам код скидываю ниже.

(P.S.: вся эта канитель происходит в функции `Set_ships`, строка 143)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
#define _CRT_NO_SECURITY_WARNINGS

 const int FIELD_SIZE = 10;

char Player1[100];
char Player2[100];

int amount_of_ship_cells_left_to_drown_P1;
int amount_of_ship_cells_left_to_drown_P2;

// [x][y], где x - вертикаль, y - горизонталь

char WaterP1 = '~';
char WaterP2 = '~';
char TorpedeP1 = 'Т';
char TorpedeP2 = 'Т';
char DestroyerP1 = 'К';
char DestroyerP2 = 'К';
char CruiserP1 = 'Э';
char CruiserP2 = 'Э';
char BattleshipP1 = 'Л';
char BattleshipP2 = 'Л';
char ShipHitP1 = 'Х';
char ShipHitP2 = 'X';
char HitMissP1 = '*';
char HitMissP2 = '*';

void ifP1Win(char* p1) {
system("cls");
cout << "Игрок " << p1 << " ПОБЕДИЛ!!! Поздравляем!" << endl;
system("pause");
}

void ifP2Win(char* p2) {
system("cls");
cout << "Игрок " << p2 << " ПОБЕДИЛ!!! Поздравляем!" << endl;
system("pause");
}

bool Cell_checker(int PlayerNumber, int asked_cell) {

char T;
char D;
char C;
char BS;

switch (PlayerNumber)
{
case 1:
{
    T = TorpedeP1;
    D = DestroyerP1;
    C = CruiserP1;
    BS = BattleshipP1;
} break;

case 2:
{
    T = TorpedeP2;
    D = DestroyerP2;
    C = CruiserP2;
    BS = BattleshipP2;
} break;

}

    if (asked_cell == T || asked_cell == D || asked_cell == C || asked_cell == 
BS)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

void Print_table(char arr[][FIELD_SIZE]) {
for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < FIELD_SIZE; j++)
    {
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}

void Print_hidden_table(char arr[][FIELD_SIZE]) {
for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < FIELD_SIZE; j++)
    {
        cout << '~' << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}


void Players_names(char* Player1, char* Player2) {

cout << "Введите имя ";
SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 3);
cout << "первого";
SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 7);
cout << " игрока() : ";

cin >> Player1;

cout << "Введите имя ";
SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 4);
cout << "второго";
SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 7);
cout << " игрока() : ";

cin >> Player2;

 }

void Create_table(char arr[][FIELD_SIZE], char c) {
for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < FIELD_SIZE; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = c;
    }
}

}

void Pass2AnotherPlayer() {
system("cls");
cout << "Переход к другому игроку. И не подглядывайте ;)" << endl;
Sleep(5000);
system("cls");
}

void Set_ships(char arr[][FIELD_SIZE], int PlayerNumber) {

char PNEnd[5];
char Torp;
char Destr;
char Crui;
char BShip;

if (PlayerNumber == 1) {
    Torp = TorpedeP1;
    Destr = DestroyerP1;
    Crui = CruiserP1;
    BShip = BattleshipP1;

    strcpy_s(PNEnd, "-ый");
}
else {
    Torp = TorpedeP2;
    Destr = DestroyerP2;
    Crui = CruiserP2;
    BShip = BattleshipP2;

    strcpy_s(PNEnd, "-ой");
}

int nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship = 1;
char type_of_ship[100];
int plant_choise_x, plant_choise_y;
int amount_of_checked_cells = 0;

while (amount_of_checked_cells < 21)
{
    system("cls");

    Print_table(arr);

    if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 4)
        strcpy_s(type_of_ship, "линкор (4 клетки для размещения)");

    if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 3)
        strcpy_s(type_of_ship, "крейсер (3 клетки для размещения)");

    if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 2)
        strcpy_s(type_of_ship, "эсминец (2 клетки для размещения)");

    if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 1)
        strcpy_s(type_of_ship, "торпедный катер (1 клетка для размещения)");


    cout << "Введите порядковый номер клетки, на которую " << PlayerNumber << PNEnd << " игрок хочет поместить кораблик (x,y).";
    cout << endl << "Помещается " << type_of_ship << "." << endl;
    cout << "   Ваши координаты: ";

    cin >> plant_choise_x >> plant_choise_y;

    if (Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y] /* само место, куда ставится клетка*/) == false
        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1] /* верхняя правая клетка */) == false
        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 1] /* нижняя левая клетка */) == false
        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 1] /* верхняя левая клетка */) == false
        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 1] /* нижняя правая клетка */) == false
        )
    {

        if (
            Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y]) == false /* нижняя */
            && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y]) == false /* верхняя */
            && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false /* левая */
            && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false /* правая */
            )
        {
            arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y] = Torp;
            amount_of_checked_cells++;
        }


        else if (amount_of_checked_cells > 4 && amount_of_checked_cells < 12) {

            if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 1)
                nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship++;

            if (arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y] == Destr
                && (Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y]) == false
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false /// choise_cords (1)
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false

                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 2][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // [1]
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 2][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // [2]
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 2][plant_choise_y]) == false /// choise_cords (2)
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false
                    )
                ||
                (arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y] == Destr                               // [2]
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y]) == false // [1]
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y]) == false /// choise_cords (1) // низ
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // нижнелевая клетка
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // нижнеправая клетка
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // лево
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // право

                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 2][plant_choise_y]) == false /// choise_cords (2) // верх
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 2][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // верхнелевая клетка
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 2][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхнеправая клетка
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // левая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // правая
                    )
                ||
                (
                    arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 1] == Destr                            // ---->
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y]) == false // [1][2]

                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y]) == false /// choise_cords (1) // низ
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // верх
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // нижнелевая клетка
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // верхнелевая клетка
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // лево

                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false /// choise_cords (2) // верх
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // низ
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 2]) == false // верхнеправая клетка
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 2]) == false // правая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 2]) == false // нижнеправая
                    )
                ||
                (
                    arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 1] == Destr // [1]                         // [2][1]
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // верх (1)
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // низ
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // правая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхнеправая клетка
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // нижнеправая кллетка

                                                                                                        // [2]
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 2]) == false // верхнелевая клетка
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // нижняя
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // верхняя
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 2]) == false // левая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 2]) == false // верхнелевая
                    )
                ||
                (
                    Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y]) == false // сама клетка
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // верхняя
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // нижняя
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // левая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // правая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // верхнелевая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхнеправая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // нижнелевая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // нижнеправая
                    )

                ) {
                arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y] = Destr;
                amount_of_checked_cells++;
            }

            if (amount_of_checked_cells >= 12)
            {
                if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 2)
                    nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship++;

                /// [1][2][3]

                //[1]
                if ((arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 1] == Crui && arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 2] == Crui
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y]) == false

                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // верхняя
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // нижняя
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // левая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // верхнелевая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // нижелевая

                                                                                                        //[2]
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхняя
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // нижнняя

                                                                                                        //[3]
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 2]) == false // верхняя
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 2]) == false // нижняя
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 3]) == false // правая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 3]) == false // верхнеправая
                    && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 3]) == false // нижнеправая
                    )
                    ||

                    /// [3][2][1]
                    (
                        Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y]) == false
                        && arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 1] == Crui && arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 2] == Crui

                        // [1]

                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // верхняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // нижняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // правая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхнеправая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // нижнеправая

                                                                                                            // [2]

                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // верхняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // нижняя

                                                                                                            // [3]

                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 2]) == false // верхняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 2]) == false // нижняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 3]) == false // левая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 3]) == false // верхнелевая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 3]) == false // нижнелевая
                        )
                    ||
                    (
                        Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y]) == false
                        && arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 1] == Crui && arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 1] == Crui

                        /// [2][1][3]
                        // [1]
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // верхняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // нижняя

                                                                                                        // [2]
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // верхняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // нижняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 2]) == false // левая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 2]) == false // верхнелевая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 2]) == false // нижнелевая

                                                                                                            // [3]
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // нижняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 2]) == false // правая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 2]) == false // верхнеправая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 2]) == false // нижеправая
                        )
                    ||
                    (
                        /*
                        [1]
                        [2]
                        [3]
                        */

                        Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y]) == false
                        && arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y] == Crui && arr[plant_choise_x + 2][plant_choise_y] == Crui

                        // [1]

                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y]) == false // верхняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // левая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // правая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // верхнелевая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхнеправая

                                                                                                            // [2]

                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false // левая
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // правая

                                                                                                            // [3]

                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхняя
                        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false // верхняя



                        )
                    ) {
                    arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y] = Crui;
                    amount_of_checked_cells++;
                }

                if (amount_of_checked_cells == 17)
                {
                    if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 3)
                        nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship++;

                    arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y] = BShip;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Введите правильную ячейку! " << endl;
        Sleep(1250);
    }
}
}

void Player_move(char arr1[][FIELD_SIZE], char arr2[][FIELD_SIZE], int 
PlayerNumber, char* p1, char* p2)
{
int choise_x;
int choise_y;

while (true) {
    system("cls");
    choise_x = 0; choise_y = 0;

    if (PlayerNumber == 1) {

        Print_table(arr1);

        cout << "\n Введите координаты клетки, в которую вы хотите стрельнуть, " << p1 << ": ";
        cout << "\n Вам осталось потопить клеток кораблей: " << amount_of_ship_cells_left_to_drown_P2;
        cin >> arr2[choise_x][choise_y];


        if ((arr2[choise_x][choise_y] == TorpedeP2
            || arr2[choise_x][choise_y] == DestroyerP2
            || arr2[choise_x][choise_y] == CruiserP2
            || arr2[choise_x][choise_y] == BattleshipP2)
            && arr2[choise_x][choise_y] != ShipHitP2
            && arr2[choise_x][choise_y] != HitMissP2)
        {
            arr2[choise_x][choise_y] = ShipHitP2;
            --amount_of_ship_cells_left_to_drown_P2;
            system("cls");
            cout << "Попадание!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }

        else if (arr2[choise_x][choise_y] == ShipHitP2
            || arr2[choise_x][choise_y] == HitMissP2) {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Вы по этой клетке уже попадали!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }

        else {
            arr2[choise_x][choise_y] = HitMissP2;
            system("cls");
            Pass2AnotherPlayer();
            break;
        }
    }

    else {
        Print_table(arr2);

        cout << "\n Введите координаты клетки, в которую вы хотите стрельнуть, " << p2 << ": ";
        cout << "\n Вам осталось потопить клеток кораблей: " << amount_of_ship_cells_left_to_drown_P1;
        cin >> arr1[choise_x][choise_y];

        if ((arr1[choise_x][choise_y] == TorpedeP1
            || arr1[choise_x][choise_y] == DestroyerP1
            || arr1[choise_x][choise_y] == CruiserP1
            || arr1[choise_x][choise_y] == BattleshipP1)
            && arr1[choise_x][choise_y] != ShipHitP1
            && arr1[choise_x][choise_y] != HitMissP1)
        {
            arr1[choise_x][choise_y] = ShipHitP1;
            --amount_of_ship_cells_left_to_drown_P1;
            system("cls");
            cout << "Попадание!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }

        else if (arr1[choise_x][choise_y] == ShipHitP1
            || arr1[choise_x][choise_y] == HitMissP1) {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Вы по этой клетке уже попадали!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }

        else {
            arr1[choise_x][choise_y] = HitMissP1;
            system("cls");
            Pass2AnotherPlayer();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}

bool Win(int ship_cells) {

if (ship_cells == 0)
    return true;
return false;
}

int main()
{
srand((unsigned)time(0));
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

char arr1[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];
char arr2[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];

Players_names(Player1, Player2);

system("cls");

cout << "Имя первого игрока: " << Player1 << endl;
cout << "Имя второго игрока: " << Player2 << endl << endl;

system("pause");

Create_table(arr1, WaterP1);
Set_ships(arr1, 1);

Pass2AnotherPlayer();

Create_table(arr2, WaterP2);
Set_ships(arr2, 2);

system("pause");

system("cls");

cout << "\t BETA TEST" << endl << endl;
cout << "Поле игрока с именем (или никнеймом) " << Player1 << endl;
Print_table(arr1);

cout << endl;

cout << "Поле игрока с именем (или никнеймом) " << Player2 << endl;
Print_table(arr2);



while (true)
{
    Player_move(arr1, arr2, 1, Player1, Player2);
    Player_move(arr1, arr2, 2, Player1, Player2);
    Win(amount_of_ship_cells_left_to_drown_P1);
    Win(amount_of_ship_cells_left_to_drown_P2);

    if (Win(amount_of_ship_cells_left_to_drown_P2) == true) {
        ifP1Win(Player1);
    }

    else if (Win(amount_of_ship_cells_left_to_drown_P1) == true) {
        ifP2Win(Player2);
    }

    cout << "Поле игрока с именем (никнеймом) " << Player1 << endl << endl;
    Print_table(arr1);

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Поле игрока с именем (никнеймом) " << Player2 << endl << endl;
    Print_table(arr2);

    system("pause");
}



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Вы хоть читали то, что я написал выше кода? Это и есть то, что Вы ищете.. Зачем удалять, потом снова добавлять то, что Вы удалили? В этом я как-то не вижу смысла...

Comment: **и минимальный код для её воспроизведения**, а не простынку всей программы. Про удаление и добавление - не понимаю вас.

Comment: Напишите снова, и лучше на С++.,  Не знаю у кого возникнет желание разобраться в этом хаосе (может грубо прозвучало, но зато честно...)

Comment: Это и есть C++ и я ЯСНО сказал, где есть вышеописанная проблема.. (напоминаю, 143 строка)

Comment: Условия работают правильно, но я не пойму, почему условия дальше не срабатывают....

Comment: Kromster, я говорил про эти изменения в плане удаления-добавления текста: https://cl.ly/0z3a001l1X2B

Comment: @Novy https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804777/286405 - посмотрите, на Си правда (впрочем, как у Вас), но может пригодится

Comment: Не беда, знаю Си :)

Comment: @Novy это внутритекстовое форматирование - так переменные и методы в тексте видны яснее. Показывается что удалено/добавлено слово, а на самом деле добавлены только ` вокруг него.

Answer (score 1):

Я не сильно разбирался в коде, но у вас за расстановку кораблей отвечает переменная nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship,

```
if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 4)
    strcpy_s(type_of_ship, "линкор (4 клетки для размещения)");

if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 3)
    strcpy_s(type_of_ship, "крейсер (3 клетки для размещения)");

if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 2)
    strcpy_s(type_of_ship, "эсминец (2 клетки для размещения)");

if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 1)
    strcpy_s(type_of_ship, "торпедный катер (1 клетка для размещения)");
```

которая инкрементируется в случае:

```
    if (
        Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x + 1][plant_choise_y]) == false /* нижняя */
        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x - 1][plant_choise_y]) == false /* верхняя */
        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y - 1]) == false /* левая */
        && Cell_checker(PlayerNumber, arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y + 1]) == false /* правая */
        )
    {
        arr[plant_choise_x][plant_choise_y] = Torp;
        amount_of_checked_cells++;
    }
    else if (amount_of_checked_cells > 4 && amount_of_checked_cells < 12) {

        if (nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship == 1)
            nmb_of_cells_for_current_ship++;
        ...
    }
```

Вот эти 2 блока условий и конфликтуют, первое условие проверяет что указана валидная клетка (по горизонтали) и, таким образом, пока у нас указывается валидная клетка блок else if никогда не выполнится.

В общем случае блок if else работает так:

```
if (условие1)
{
   ...
}
else if (условие2)
{
   ...
}
else if (условиеN)
{
   ...
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

Если условие1 верно, то выполняется блок кода 1, условия 2 и дальше даже не проверяются. Если условие1 неверно, то проверяется следующее за ним, до первого успешного, а если такого нет, то выполняется блок else.

P.S. подтвердить мою догадку можно введя координаты, некорректные по вертикали или горизонтали, после расстановки 4х однопалубников, тогда код проскочит первое условие и перейдет на следующее, которое нам и нужно.

Comment: Нашёл причину этого дела: код составлен у меня как попало. Дело в том, что я делал иф в ифе, в котором есть ещё один иф, в котором есть остальные ифы, включая тот иф, который отвечает за счёт кол-ва клеток кораблей. Как-то так. Сейчас переправляю код.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, поставив доп. условие, позволяющее перейти на поставление двухпалубных, а не однопалубных кораблей:
 `amount_of_checked_cells >= 0 && amount_of_checked_cells < 4`